# Почему и как этот код работает? В 'd' ведь кладётся ссылка на дату, но в массиве, внутри, всё нормально заполняется

Tags: javascript

```
var date = new Date();  
var d = date;
d = [  
    '0' + d.getDate(),  
    '0' + (d.getMonth() + 1),  
    '' + d.getFullYear(),  
    '0' + d.getHours(),  
    '0' + d.getMinutes()  
      ];
alert();  
alert(date);
```

Comment: Кладётся объект `Date` с текущей датой и временем. Подробно можно в учебнике глянуть - https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime

Comment: _В 'd' ведь кладётся ссылка на дату, но в массиве, внутри, всё нормально заполняется_ - а какое было ожидаемое поведение?

Comment: Но ведь ведь потом в d кладётся массив

Comment: learn.javascript.ru/datetime, всё прочитано и решено, но вот этот момент в последней задачи я так и не пойму

Comment: Просто порядок выполнения операций такой. Сначала выполняется складывание строк первого элемента массива, добавление его в массив, и так далее. Операция присваивания массива в d выполняется самой последней.

Comment: **1** Вы создаете дату `var date = new Date();`, потом делаете что-то, потом выводите `alert(date);`. При вызове `alert` выполняется `.toString()`, что дает `Thu Oct 20 2016 23:07:50 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))`. [Преобразование объектов: toString и valueOf](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion). **2** Это не с++, где есть объект и есть ссылка. В js нельзя получить значение ссылки на область памяти. У вас просто две ссылки на объект `new Date();`. То есть в `var date` хранится то же самое, что и в `var d`.

Comment: Прекрасно, можно спать спокойно теперь=)
Вся проблема в присваивании массива, его порядка была, буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор присваивания в яваскрипте правоассоциативен - это означает, что сначала вычисляется значение правой части и лишь затем результат присваивается левой.

В данном случае сначала вычисляются значения массива, и лишь затем переменной `d` присваивается новое значение.